# uiSlider variable stays the same when posting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using noUiSlider and I am trying to pass the value of the slider through a form to a mysql database. The form is working fine and posting to the database but the value of the slider does not change from it's original start value. I have tried pretty much every possible angle I can think of and researched everywhere, I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Please have a look and let me know what the problem is. kudos to the person who sets me straight. Thanks.

```
    $("#rangeSlider").noUiSlider({
        start: 7000,
        step: 1000,
        behaviour: 'snap',
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 15000
        },          
        serialization: {
            lower: [
                $.Link({
                    // Place the value in the #value element,
                    // using the text method.
                    target: $("#value"),
                    method: "text",
                    format: {
                        decimals: 0,
                        thousand: ',',
                        prefix: '£'
                    }
                }),     
            ],
        },  
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            $('#amount').val('#rangeSlider', ui.value);
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + $( "#rangeSlider" ).val() );
```

Comment: From what i can see here, you are not using .val() properly. Here is a link to the jQuery docs on .val() http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: the .val() is used to call the sliders valus as per http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write

Comment: yes you can take that out it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally solved it :)

```
    $("#rangeSlider").noUiSlider({
        start: 7000,
        step: 1000,
        behaviour: 'snap',
        connect: 'lower',
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 15000
        },          
        serialization: {
            lower: [
                $.Link({
                    // Place the value in the #value element,
                    // using the text method.
                    target: $("#amount"),
                    type: "post"
                }), 
                $.Link({
                    // Place the value in the #value element,
                    // using the text method.
                    target: $("#value"),
                    method: "text",
                    format: {
                        decimals: 0,
                        thousand: ',',
                        prefix: '£'
                    }
                }),     
            ],
        },          
    });
```

This posts the answer to the database as well as showing the value of the slider whilst you are sliding it :)